# Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: wamp

I'm running prestashop 1.4 with wamp 2.5 and im getting the in error file (.htaccess)

> Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined
> by a module not included in the server configuration

I didn't get it in previous installation (wamp 2.4)

I read this

> Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined
> by a module not included in the server configuration -
> AddOutputFilterByType has moved from the core to mod_filter, which
> must be loaded.

in apache web site, not sure what it means.

any way the htaccess is created automatically.

Comment: down grade to wamp 2.4 solve the problem

Comment: It would be useful to see that actual line from your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Enable the '**filter_module**' module in apache.

[Wamp icon] > Apache > Apache modules > filter_module

Downgrading to wamp 2.4 will *avoid but not solve* the problem. Enabling filter_module allows for AddOutputFilterByType htaccess support on wamp 2.5

Answer (score 6):

To fix this, enable mod_filter and restart Apache. mod_filter is required in 2.4, although in 2.2 was not the case.

To enable it, open your `httpd.conf` file and uncomment the line

```
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
```

Then restart the Apache services and you're done.

Source: https://www.nivas.hr/blog/2012/08/10/upgrade-to-apache-2-4-and-addoutputfilterbytype-issue/

Answer (score 2):

You can change your .htaccess to initially check if the filter module is enabled or not, and then apply the attributes.

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType ...
</IfModule>
```